# How can you deloop a monoidal category more than once?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

A monoidal category can be thought of as a bicategory with one point. This is supposed to be a special case of delooping which I also don't understand.

If a monoidal category forms a bicategory with one object then what happens if you have a category that can be thought of as monoidal in **multiple** ways?

For example, suppose you have a category C with both products and coproducts.

You can hack things in by taking the product of both bicategories.

A map is a tuple of objects of C.
Composition is implemented as

$$ (a_0, a_1) \circ (b_0, b_1) = (a_0 + b_0, a_1 \times b_1) $$

But I'm not sure this is the best way of thinking of things or what delooping more than once would really mean.

Taking the product is also suggestive of some sort of comma category which makes intuitive geometric sense to me. But this doesn't seem quite right.

$$ \mathrm{Hom}(x, y) = \{a, b \in C \, | \, a \times x = b + y  \}$$

You'd want at least one functor in here other than identity. But I feel like the exponential has the wrong variance.

Comment: Delooping multiple times has an established meaning and it is not that. An example of a thing that can be delooped twice (indeed, infinitely many times) is an abelian group.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $C$ is a monoidal category. Then there is a $2$-category, call it $BC$, with a single object $\bullet$, with $1$-morphisms the objects of $C$ and composition given by $\otimes_C$.

It satisfies $\Omega(BC,\bullet) \simeq C$, where for a $2$-category $A$ and an object $a$, I let $\Omega(A,a)$ denote the monoidal category of endomorphisms of $a$

Furthermore, note that for $A,A'$ two $2$-categories and $a\in A, a'\in A'$, $\Omega(A\times A', (a,a')) \simeq \Omega(A,a) \times \Omega(A',a')$.

What you're describing is taking $C^\times$ and $C^\sqcup$, their deloopings $B(C^\times)$ and $B(C^\sqcup)$ and then their product. Well if you loop that product, you get a product of the loops, i.e. $C^\times \times C^\sqcup$. So this does *not* mix the two structures in any way, it just puts them side by side.

As pointed out by Zhen Lin in the comments, this is *not* what "delooping more than once" means. Delooping more than once means that $BC$ has the structure of a monoidal $2$-category, and that you deloop that structure to a $3$-category with only one object, in a similar way.

This can happen if and only if your original monoidal structure has a *braiding*. As S.C. explained in their answer, this means that the monoidal product $\otimes_C$ "distributes" over itself, which is equivalent to there being two monoidal structures compatible in a suitable way.

If you want to go further, then your braiding has to be symmetric; but then you can deloop "up to infinity". That the braiding be symmetric in this case is equivalent to the existence of a third monoidal structure which is also suitably compatible (let me not spell out what that means).

This is, however, only the beginning of a long and complicated (but fascinating) story; because you could ask what is required to deloop a monoidal $2$-category once, twice, three times, ... ? Or a monoidal $3$-category ? And the answers get more complicated each time.

For ($\infty$- or $n$-)groupoids with all objects invertible under $\otimes$, this is much easier although still nontrivial and interesting - it's related to so-called $E_n$-spaces and the little disk operads.

Answer (score 3):

Something interesting happens in the case where the two monoidal operations distribute over each other (and this is what Zhen Lin is talking about in the comments). For simplicity, we'll consider monoids, rather than monoidal categories, but it generalizes if you use isomorphisms rather than equalities.

Let's say we have a monoid with two operations $\otimes$ and $\oplus$. After delooping once using $\otimes$, we have a category with an object $\bullet$, $\hom(\bullet, \bullet)$ is the original monoid, and composition there is the same as $\otimes$. We'd like to be able to use $\oplus$ to make this into a monoidal category and thus deloop again, but one condition stands in the way: functorality.

$\bullet \oplus' \bullet$ can just be $\bullet$, but more importantly, $f \oplus' g$ can be $f \oplus g$ (remember that $f$ and $g$ are are elements of the original monoid, so $\oplus$ is defined on them).

Unfortunately (or perhaps fortunately, given what eventually happens), $\oplus'$ isn't a functor without further assumptions. The main thing is that we need $(f \circ g) \oplus' (h \circ k) = (f \oplus' h) \circ (g \oplus' k)$, or equivalently, that $(f \otimes g) \oplus (h \otimes k) = (f \oplus h) \otimes (g \oplus k)$. In other words, $\otimes$ and $\oplus$ need to distribute over each other.

For the action of $\oplus'$ on the identity, we just need $id_\bullet \oplus' id_\bullet = id_\bullet$. Since $\oplus$ has its own unit $e$, this follows from the distributivity above.

$$
\begin{align}
id_\bullet \oplus' id_\bullet &= (id_\bullet \oplus' id_\bullet) \circ id_\bullet\\
&= (id_\bullet \oplus' id_\bullet) \circ (id_\bullet \oplus' e)\\
&= (id_\bullet \circ id_\bullet) \oplus' (id_\bullet \circ e)\\
&= id_\bullet \oplus' e\\
&= id_\bullet
\end{align}
$$

The other structural isomorphisms for a monoidal category hold strictly (mainly because we started with two monoids), so that was the hardest part.

So from here, you can deloop again to get a bicategory with one 0-cell and one 1-cell where horizontal composition of the 2-cells is one monoidal operation and vertical composition is the other.

Perhaps unfortunately, this condition of distribution forces both operations to not only be the same operation, but also be commutative. This is known as the [Eckmann-Hilton argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument). One part of it already appeared above with the proof that $id_\bullet \oplus' id_\bullet = id_\bullet$.

In the generalization for monoidal categories, non-strictness gets you a little leeway. Making $\oplus'$ into a pseudofunctor again forces the two operations to be isomorphic, but now the result is only [braided](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/braided+monoidal+category#in_terms_of_higher_monoidal_structure), rather than symmetric That is, the isomorphisms $a \otimes b \equiv b \otimes a$ aren't their own inverses. After delooping a braided monoidal category once, you get a bicategory with a single 0-cell. The hom-category on that 0-cell is the original monoidal category and compositition of 1-cells is the monoidal operation. Being braided means that this bicategory is itself (bi?)monoidal so that it can be delooped again to get a tricategory with one 0-cell and one 1-cell. And then the hom-category on that 1-cell is the original braided monoidal category.

Having three monoidal operations with suitable distributivity requirements gets you to symmetric monoidal categories. Once again, all three operations collapse into a single, symmetric operation.